# How to learn math properly?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

A little information about me:

I really like learning math,physics,despite the fact that sometimes i rage when i don't find the pattern of a certain problem in less than 30 minutes (but i guess that you gotta relieve the anger somehow,I'm trying to deal with this).

Soon (I hope) I'll be attending a university to become an IT specialist,luckily for me to get major you need to study both Calculus 1 and Calculus 2 + Statistics but,unfortunately,no discrete mathematics.
So eventually I'll be learning discrete mathematics on my own just because I'm both interested in it and due to the fact that IMO it is one of the greatest branches of mathematics for anyone who learns about digital electronics/technologies,programming languages (+ it is always nice to know that it can be used in sandbox video-games which have such simple elements of digital electronics such as logic gates to make sophisticated circuits and logical contraptions).

As you might have guessed I've only studied general algebra,geometry,precalculus.Nothing extraordinary.

I have a few questions regarding ways to study math for years to come without guilt,knowing that I'm doing it properly.

First of all,what really bothers me are times when I'm stuck on problems,I know very well that this will ALWAYS happen to me,it is impossible to avoid these situations,what I want to know is:

**In order to improve mathematical skills,strengthen your abilities to solve problems,are you allowed to look at solutions,search for hints IF you set yourself a certain limit,after how much time of "no luck" you are allowed to do this?**

Like look at the solution only after 30-35 minutes of absolute zero progress.

**Is this the right way?** Because I've seen **VERY negative reaction of some mathematicians on different forums towards this idea,stating that "there won't be any solutions when you reach graduate math" and "it's better to ponder for hours over a problem than looking in the solution"**.

**Note that I will be abiding by this very method (that i'm still searching for) for years to come,for learning all kinds of math**.

Another question is about proof learning:

Is it efficient to learn proofs by:

**1)reading author's proof,2)doing best to understand every single step of it,3)trying to write down the very same proof pretending to be an author proceeding from the same logic that author has used,4)repeating 3) until proof is firmly stuck in your head**?

Thanks.

Comment: About the frustration: there are aspects of mathematics that are unresolved. There are aspects of mathematics that some of the best minds have tried to solve but were unable. There will be questions you won't know how to answer, this is normal. Step away from the problem and return at another time. About learning proofs: mathematics is an art, learn from other artists but do not replicate it in exactly the same way. Develop your own artistic signature.

Comment: This reminds me of the "experience of being a frustrated artist" portion of [A Mathematician's Lament](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf).

Comment: I've deleted my answer and simply flagged the poor-quality question. Next time I'll know better than to try and help.

Comment: @SZN mmm.... waffles

Comment: "reading author's proof,2)doing best to understand every single step of it,3)trying to write down the very same proof pretending to be an author proceeding from the same logic that author has used,4)repeating 3) until proof is firmly stuck in your head?"  That's what I do, but I'm a vagabond, not a mathematician.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hello,Benjamin.Judging from your experience,could you tell me,how do you deal with proofs (do you instantly try to prove a certain proposition yourself or you check author's proof first?) and how do you deal with problems with solutions (but you don't look into it yet) that you cannot solve for some time?
I know that in more advanced topics of mathematics 30 minutes of thinking is ridiculously low amount of time,but then again I'm not even sure if it's even ALLOWED to look at the solution when being stuck if you really want to LEARN and not just barely pass.Forgive my nuisance.

Comment: @KenanMamedov There's a difference between spending 30 minutes trying different approaches and spending 30 minutes being **stuck**.  If you're really at the point where you've been stuck for 30 minutes (i.e. you're out of ideas of how to make a new attempt or incremental progress), I think it's time to look for a hint.  It's useful to be able to reach out to someone who can give you the right kind of hint to nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: @KenanMamedov Before you reach out for help, you should always ask "what haven't I tried yet; does this other idea seem like it might work?"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks a lot!!Now I know that if you're actually stuck,only then you must start searching for a hint to advance further.Thank you!

Comment: @KenanMamedov I think that's a fair assessment; certainly something to strive for.

Comment: I think when you read proofs, points 1 and 2 are enough, but you also need to think about what the ideas are that allowed the author to find the proof. Sometimes this is too difficult, and if it only happens sometimes, that's okay. As for solving problems,  I think it really depends. Often I put a problem to one side if I'm not able to solve it, and then return to it later. Sometimes the solution (or a good idea) will come to me in the shower. But if you think you won't have the motivation to return to the problem later, then it's better to get a hint and continue than to drop it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fair to look at the problem's solution after you spent a certain time with it where you literally made no progress. Your time is limited, and certainly at university level, you don't have much time to make lots of exercises.

A couple of hints when you are making exercises:

- You must know your theory before you attempt a problem. Proofs in the theory can give you ideas how to tackle new problems. If you don't know the relevant theorems, you won't get far either.
- Write out all definitions that you have applied to the information you are given. Try to write down as much as you can and try to get as far as possible. If you get stuck, start working backwards: 'How can I reach this conclusion? Well, if I can prove that statement, I am done.' Chances are that you can prove that statement with the information you have and you can connect the two parts of your proof in the middle.
- Really don't spend too long on one exercise. When you get stuck, move on. Return later. Maybe take a walk and think about it. I have solved many problems where I didn't even have the problem statement at hand.

Also, try not to get frustrated. This leads nowhere.

Good luck!

Comment: I think spending long time on an exercise is super useful. Any wrong solutions you tried, you know it leads nowhere. If I can say solve exercise in less that 2 min I consider I learned (almost) nothing. And if by chance you find it, this is very rewarding. Of course most of the time you didn't find it but at least you are sure that you tried everything you could try from the theory, etc

Comment: Yes, it is certainly useful. But if you are a university student (thus speaking for what the OP is becoming), you don't have time to make lots of exercises. Mastering the theory takes a lot of time, so not much time left for exercises. So if you spend many time on 1 exercise, at the end of the day you won't have enough time.

Comment: I'm also a university student, lot of my friends got time for gym, etc ... and could still finish their degree. I don't think it's hard to find say 30 minutes a day and spend time on one problem, trying to solve it, even if you know you have good chance to fail. If you just do some easy exercises, don't spend the time to try hardest one, then little to little you forget everything. The only subject from my undergrad I remember very well were the subjects I was doing more complicated exercises. Of course it's not a generality and everybody has his own vision of how to learn math.